# Set Time Out TCP [ setsockopt + SO_RCVTIMEO ]

Tags: sockets, tcp, timeout, settimeout, setsockopt

I want to ask about something when I want to set timeout with specific socket i call this function

```
void Server::setReceiveTimeout(unsigned int timeout, SOCKET clientSocket)
{
    if (setsockopt(clientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout)))
        cout << "could not set socket option " << endl;
}
```

and it is working well

now my question

if i set the clientsocket to a specific timeout ..how could i return clientsocket back so there is no timeout?

for example
settimeout(3000);
recv

then after recv I want to return it back to the state where no time out How ?

your help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Set it to zero. ["If the timeout is set to zero (the default), then the operation will never timeout."](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)

Comment: Thank you EJP :)

but the problem is that I am doing something like this


Send();
setTimeOut(3000);
recv();
setTimeOut(0);

it is not working why ??
do i have to set the timeout before sending or receiving ?

Comment: I don't understand this question.